# Is it possible to write-access Local Storage from the Node?

Tags: offchain-worker, offchain-storage, configuration, local

My use case is this:
an Offchain Worker sends Http requests to certain endpoints.

These endpoints are hardcoded on chain under current implementation.

I would like to be able to configure those endpoints and some other parameters locally once the Node is up, so the configuration is local-specific.

So I wonder if there is a way to access the Local Storage from the Outer Node ?

I can compile `StorageValueRef::persistent` on the Outer Node after the essential tasks are spawned, however it panics because of calling out of Externalities context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is an RPC method.

`offchain_localStorageSet`

[image]

---

1. you need to enable `--offchian-indexing` for your node
2. you need to enable `--rpc-methods unsafe` for your node
3. you'd better don't expose your RPC endpoint, just use this in private network, because anyone can call this to set the storage

Comment: Cool. This seems to fit  exactly my use case. Thanks a lot !

Comment: So, could you please mark this as the answer?